# -bash: syntax error near unexpected token `newline' during K3S upgrade

Tags: k3s

currently running K3S version v1.27.6+k3s1 on Ubuntu 22.04. When trying to update like curl -sfL https://get.k3s.io | <EXISTING_K3S_ENV> sh -s - <EXISTING_K3S_ARGS>, it instantly fails with error -bash: syntax error near unexpected token `newline'. Any idea how to fix it?

Tried to find a solution at k3s website but no success. When only using curl -sfL https://get.k3s.io without additional parameters it shows the install script.

Comment: I fixed it now. Just ran curl -sfL https://get.k3s.io | sh - and it worked.